# The file does not exists Mac OSX El Capitán 10.11.3

Tags: macos, bash, file

I hope somebody can help me. I asked a friend of mine for a copy of a file called " ". Apparently the file is in my USB drive but inaccessible (on my computer). In his works fine.

```bash
MacBook-Pro-de-Alvaro:Volumes alvarodt$ ls
ALVARODT    ALVARODT 1  Macintosh HD
MacBook-Pro-de-Alvaro:Volumes alvarodt$ cd ALVARODT\ 1/
MacBook-Pro-de-Alvaro:ALVARODT 1 alvarodt$ ls
ACUERDOS INTERNACIONALES EN MATERIA DE EDUCACIÓN.pdf
ALVARODT
EXPOSICION
RESUMEN DEFENSA AÉREA.pdf
System Volume Information
MacBook-Pro-de-Alvaro:ALVARODT 1 alvarodt$ open RESUMEN\ DEFENSA\ AÉREA.pdf 
The file /Volumes/ALVARODT 1/RESUMEN DEFENSA AÉREA.pdf does not exist.
MacBook-Pro-de-Alvaro:ALVARODT 1 alvarodt$
```